# Marklogic - How to hide elements node

Tags: marklogic

I try to exclude unwanted node in documents. I could not figure out how to make it works.
for example multiple documents:

```
<doc:Record Type="testdata" xmlns:doc="http://db/test/record">
  <meta:Metadata xmlns:meta="http://db/test/record/meta">

    <meta:docid>09266</meta:docid>
    <meta:Collections>
       <meta:Collection>Universities</meta:Collection>
    </meta:Collections>
    <meta:NonFundingSources>
      <meta:TotalNonDODFunding>0 </meta:TotalNonDODFunding>
    </meta:NonFundingSources>
  </meta:Metadata>
</doc:Record>
```

---

The result should hide the "NonFundingSources" element and return all other element nodes.

```
 <doc:Record Type="testdata" xmlns:doc="http://db/test/record">
   <meta:Metadata xmlns:meta="http://db/test/record/meta">

     <meta:docid>09266</meta:docid>
     <meta:Collections>
       <meta:Collection>Universities</meta:Collection>
     </meta:Collections>
  </meta:Metadata>
</doc:Record>
```

---

In my code I retrieve all elements, but I could not figure out how to hide (remove) the unwanted element node before saving to the file system.

```
let $uris := cts:uris((),
                  (),
                  cts:and-query((
                          cts:collection-query("/ure/univs"),
                          cts:field-word-query("dc",("a","be","x")),
                          cts:field-range-query("crd",">=","2011-01-01"),
                          cts:field-range-query("crd","<","2012-01-01")
                  ))

                 )

   for $uri in $uris

   let $docNumber := fn:data($uri//meta:docid)

   return xdmp:save(fn:concat("/report/",$docNumber,".xml") ,$uri )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to prune the element would be to apply an XSLT that uses the [identity template](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/redaction) to copy most content and an empty template matching on the element(s) that you want to remove:

```
declare variable $XSLT := 
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:meta="http://db/test/record/meta">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <!--by default, every attribute and node is copied to the output-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--Whenever this element is matched, no output is generated for it, 
        or any of it's descendants -->
    <xsl:template match="meta:NonFundingSources"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>;

for $doc in cts:search(doc(),  
                        cts:and-query((
                          cts:collection-query("/ure/univs"),
                          cts:field-word-query("dc",("a","be","x")),
                          cts:field-range-query("crd",">=","2011-01-01"),
                          cts:field-range-query("crd","<","2012-01-01")
                        ))
              )

let $docNumber := $doc//meta:docid/string()
(: transform the document, removing content that we don't want :)
let $redacted := xdmp:xslt-eval($XSLT, $doc)
return 
  xdmp:save(fn:concat("/report/",$docNumber,".xml"), $redacted )
```

MarkLogic also has [element level security](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/redaction) and [redaction](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/redaction) features, which could be used to hide or redact content.